# Using innerHTML of <select> for windows.open()

Tags: javascript, html

On a page of my website I want user to select one choice of a  and when they click on **"connect"** it open a new tab with the correct link.

code :

```
<select name="choice" id="choice">
    <option value="Server1.html">Server1</option>
    <option value="Server2.html">Server2</option>
    <option value="Server3.html">Server3</option>
</select>
    <input type="button" name="go_button" id= "go_button" value="go"   onclick="go_to_the_link()"/>
<script>
function go_to_this_link(){
    var element = document.getElementById("choice");
    var link = element.innerHTML;
    myWindow = window.open(link,"_blank");
}
</script>
```

According to the documentation this should works ... but since I'm new to JS and not expert in HTML I must have failed something.
I want to use JS only and make something that also works with datalist.

Any help is welcome !

Comment: Shouldn't you be targeting the `.value` not the `.innerHTML`? **.innerHTML:** Specifies the HTML content of an element - **.value:** A String, representing the value of the value attribute of the option element

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
Ok I had 2 problem :

1. In order to post this on stackoverflow I changed all my variable and function name, and I forgot to change one ...
2. As said in the comment, I needed to use "value" and not innerHTML. I tried with value once but it also failed that's why I gave up this, I guess something else was wrong.

Thx for helping solving the problem !

(working) code :

```
<select name="choice" id="choice">
    <option value="Server1.html">Server1</option>
    <option value="Server2.html">Server2</option>
    <option value="Server3.html">Server3</option>
</select>
    <input type="button" name="go_button" id= "go_button" value="go"   onclick="go_to_the_link()"/>
<script>
function go_to_the_link(){
    var element = document.getElementById("choice");
    var link = element.value;
    myWindow = window.open(link,"_blank");
}
</script>
```